# Angular Manipulate Carousel

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Hey guys is there a way i could manipulate my boostrap carousel in Angular?

My Carousel looks something like this

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
   <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
   <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
 </ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
  </div>
</div>
```

I got the example from: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

How can i create a function to switch slides?
As in (If Z === true > show X Slide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better to use the Angular port of libraries instead of the generic ones. You can use the [ngx-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) which is the Angular port of Bootstrap.

After that, you can use the `activeSlide` in order to show the slide you want.

`activeSlide` is a two-way binding property that will change when the slide is changed by the carousel too.

Here is a snippet:

```
<carousel [(activeSlide)]="activeSlideIndex" >
  <slide *ngFor="let slide of slides; let index=index">
    <img [src]="slide.image" alt="image slide" style="display: block; width: 100%;">
 
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4>Slide {{index}}</h4>
      <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
    </div>
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

and in you TS file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 
@Component({
  selector: 'demo-carousel-dynamic',
  templateUrl: './dynamic.html'
})
export class DemoCarouselDynamicComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() myFlag: boolean;
  slides: { image: string }[] = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg'];
  activeSlideIndex = 0;
 
  ngOnInit() {
    if (myFlag) {
      this.activeSlideIndex = 2;
    }
  }
  
}
```

And for sure, don't forget to import the carousel module:

```
// RECOMMENDED
import { CarouselModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/carousel';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CarouselModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

You can check the full carousel documentation [here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/carousel).